# Openpyxl's xml changes break my workbook. I need a fix or alternative

Tags: python, excel, xml, openpyxl

I have a very large .xlsm that is used as a template. There are 4 blank tabs in the workbook that the rest of the workbook looks at. Those sheets are all text formatted with no other formatting needed. I have a program that:

- Executes an SQL query,
- Copies and renames the template based on my input,
- Populates those 4 tabs with my query data,(openpyxl)
- Saves the notebook.(openpyxl)

I recently introduced a new version of the template, and now when I open the output file I get the following error (after telling excel it can recover the notebook.)

> Replaced Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet31.xml part with XML error.  The namespace for 'xmlns:xml' is reserved and it can only be declared as 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace'. Line 8, column 90.

I have found the issue in the xml for the sheet in question.

If I take this line:

```
</f><v></v></c><c r="E2" s="132"><f xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" aca="1" ca="1" ref="E2" t="array" ns0:space="preserve">
```

And I update it to:

```
</f><v></v></c><c r="E2" s="132"><f aca="1" ca="1" ref="E2" t="array" xml:space="preserve">
```

...I can open it with no problem!

Comparing the template's xml for that sheet to what openpyxl outputs, I am sure that it essentially rewriting the entire notebook as it best understands it is the problem. **I need either an alternative that is capable of simply writing to those tabs and keeping the rest of the notebook in tact, or I need to know if there is something in the openpyxl code/commands themselves that I can change in order to avoid this.**

It is notable that the cell that the xml is on is an array formula that targets a named range on another tab (something that exists elsewhere in the notebook), and that if I delete that formula or strip out certain pieces of it in the template that the file that is exported has no problems opening at all, but that was done for testing and no workaround I've tried for the formula is safe from the error.

**EDIT:**
I have verified no trailing spaces in the formula, and even tried it with spaces removed in any output. The error persists.

Here is the formula in the cell that the xml error will occur on:

```
{=
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
IF(A2="","",IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2&"|"&$C2,INDIRECT("'"&INDEX(Lookup_sheets,MATCH(1,--(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&Lookup_sheets&"'!$T:$T"),$A2&"|"&$C2)>0),0))&"'!$T:$U"),2,FALSE),"NOT FOUND")),
INDEX(SIMP_CONF_FIND,1),INDEX(SIMP_CONF_REP,1)),
INDEX(SIMP_CONF_FIND,2),INDEX(SIMP_CONF_REP,2)),
INDEX(SIMP_CONF_FIND,3),INDEX(SIMP_CONF_REP,3)),
INDEX(SIMP_CONF_FIND,4),INDEX(SIMP_CONF_REP,4))}
```

Comment: You can probably avoid the problem by removing any trailing space from the formula.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I made sure I didn't have any trailing spaces, that didn't fix it. Then I ALSO removed all line-breaks, and that did it... I don't understand it, because there are line breaks in a million other places in my template, but that did it!

Comment: Glad to know you got it working. I think someone else had a similar issue recently so I will see if we can tweak this. The directive is important for XML so that whitespace is preserved (think about the contents of cells). Obviously, Excel doesn't like this in formulae.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, removing all of the trailing spaces in the formula, AND all of the line-breaks in the formula seems to have solved the problem! I don't understand it because I have line breaks in plenty of other places, including other array formulas, but that fixed it here.

**EDIT:**
Being very frustrated that I had other formulas with line-breaks, I went to see if there was a difference between ALL of the others and this particular formula and found this was the ONLY formula in the sheet where I had a line-break immediately following the first "=". Once I updated it to the following formula, it worked, and I was able to keep my line-breaks!

```
{=SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
IF(A2="","",IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2&"|"&$C2,INDIRECT("'"&INDEX(Lookup_sheets,MATCH(1,--(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&Lookup_sheets&"'!$T:$T"),$A2&"|"&$C2)>0),0))&"'!$T:$U"),2,FALSE),"NOT FOUND")),
INDEX(SIMP_CONF_FIND,1),INDEX(SIMP_CONF_REP,1)),
INDEX(SIMP_CONF_FIND,2),INDEX(SIMP_CONF_REP,2)),
INDEX(SIMP_CONF_FIND,3),INDEX(SIMP_CONF_REP,3)),
INDEX(SIMP_CONF_FIND,4),INDEX(SIMP_CONF_REP,4))}
```

Thanks Charlie Clark for pointing my brain toward the one combination I hadn't tried yet in all of my troubleshooting!